# Amplify exposing clientId in frontend application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building a static React website hosting with cloudfront and S3, I found that the Cognito clientId and userPoolId are stored in the frontend javascript which can be viewed in browser view page source. I have backend API using API Gateway trusting the access token from Cognito. I am wondering if attacker take the clientId and userPoolId to their own website which look very similar to my website, they will be able to render the Authenticator(Login page), which user will be able to login. Then their malicious website will receive access token from Cognito and they can then call my backend API with the access token. API Gateway will accept the access token since the access token is a valid token from Cognito.

Is this a valid concern and how can I protect my application from this? Exposing the clientId and userPoolId in frontend and allowing other website to connect to my Cognito.

Are attackers able to render the login page on their website using clientId and userPoolId from my application?